# What changed in mobile Safari due to the iOS 4.0 upgrade?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

Where can I find a list of the changes to iPhone Safari's handling of CSS, HTML, JavaScript etc.? Behaviour changes, deprecated `-webkit` extensions and also new features and capabilities.

I didn't have any luck with a quick Google search or scanning the Apple developer pages, and a changelog would help a lot before I start attempting to debug a web app that isn't working properly since upgrading to iOS 4.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it happens, the bug went away in iOS 4.1, which only reinforces my desire for some kind of changelog.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://rmp135.posterous.com/the-definitive-list-of-ios4-changes) looks pretty accurate from what I have observed.

Comment: That only lists changes to bundled applications, not browser API changes.